# Loading local image in webview

Tags: html, css, objective-c, uiwebview

So basically im creating HTML code as a string for my webview. Then when the code is created I call

```
[webView loadHTMLString:formattedString baseURL:nil];
```

And the webview shows the webpage nicely with css and images. The images are coded like

```
background-image: url('http://URL TO IMAGE');
```

But when I download the image first and save it to my root folder

```
- (NSString *)absolutePathToCacheDirectory {
NSString *path = [cacheDirectory stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
if ([path characterAtIndex:0] != '/') {
    path = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"~/Documents/%@", path] stringByExpandingTildeInPath];
}
return path;
}
```

And then try to set the background-image like this:

```
background-image: url('/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/D2E85045-EB9E-4481-9219-231886DCB822/Documents/cache/IMAGENAME');
```

It doesn't show the image. I tried with and without the quotes. Even did a check with FileManager to see if the file exists @path and it does exist.

Somebody knows why my image isn't showing in the webview when I try to load it locally?

Comment: how are you saving your image locally ?

Comment: [fm createFileAtPath:fileName contents:data attributes:nil];

When I look up the file in Finder it's there and a preview is given. But I just noticed its of type document.

Comment: Its missing the extension. Trying to fix that en try again with the correct extension

Comment: Oke so i've added an extenstion and all images are jpg. However still not showing up in my webview. I tried Imagename.jpg and without .jpg but its not showing (FileManager says it exists btw and I see the image in Finder). HTML string is like:

background-image: url('/Users/USERNAME/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/4FED6D3D-F24A-49E8-802A-61DC91D73193/Documents/cache/imagename.jpg');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke I found out my problem. Just forgot to set the baseURL when loading the html. It now points to the folder where my images are stored.